# AWS registering a loadbalancer and ECS with a targetgroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, target, amazon-elb

I am using terraform to register a target group with a LoadBalancer.
As I understand it. I use the resource aws_lb_target_group_attachment
with the vars

target_group_arn which is set to the arn of the target group"

target_id  not sure what to set this to.

target_group_arn is the arn of the target group.
But I am not sure what target_id is, looking at the docs it says

The ID of the target. This is the Instance ID for an instance, or the container ID for an ECS container.

So I am guessing its referring to the ECS container. My target is an instance.
But when I look at my ECS cluster there is no ID on the console.

I have created the cluster, and I have created 3 service. Neither have an ID.

What is it that I am missing, or I need to create.

Thanks

Comment: I've noticed that almost all your questions got answered yet not a single answer was accepted. Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered. @MarkB answer is one of those that should be accepted.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I replied and thanked the contributor for helping me. Is there a button  or something I should press to accept a reply.

Comment: Yes, there is a button. A "tick" like under the upvote/downvote buttons.

Comment: Found it.I did not know there were rules about ticks and votes sorry I voted up and ticked.

Comment: Thank you. If you want, you can revisit your past questions and their answers, and review if the answers were helpful for acceptance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I am using terraform to register a target group with a LoadBalancer.
> As I understand it. I use the resource aws_lb_target_group_attachment

The `aws_lb_target_group_attachment` resource is for registering targets with the target group. You could use this to manually register ECS containers with the target group, however ECS can manage this target group relationship for you. By allowing ECS to manage it for you, any time a container is added, such as during auto-scaling, it will be automatically added to the load balancer by ECS.

---

You will need to create an `aws_lb`, and an `aws_lb_target_group`. Then create an `aws_lb_listener` which is assigned to the `aws_lb`, and has an action that forwards requests to the `aws_lb_target_group`. The listener "connects" the target group to the load balancer.

Now in your `aws_ecs_service` definition, you need to create a `load_balancer` block which tells ECS how to register a specific container with the target group. By doing it this way ECS will manage registering all instances of that container (in all the service's tasks) with the target group.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have created a aws_lb and a aws_lb_target_group and a aws_lb_listener.  If I understand you correctly I do not need to create a resource aws_lb_target_group_attachment.  That instead the aws_lb_listener will be responsible for forwarding requests to the aws_lb_target_group#

Comment: Now the second part connecting the ECS to the target group. I think you are saying I in my aws_ecs_service I create a  load_balancer, which contains the following target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.foo.arn. Thank you very much. That was very helpful.

Comment: Yes, you need to add a `load_balancer` block to the ECS service, with the `target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.foo.arn` as well as specifying the container name, and container port that the traffic should be forwarded to. You do NOT need to create a `aws_lb_target_group_attachment`. That is primarily for attaching EC2 instances to a target group if you have no auto-scaling in place. For auto-scaled EC2 instance, or ECS managed containers, you let those service manage the target group attachment for you.

Comment: Thank you, sorry to ask another question the container name, is that the name of the ECS Cluster or the name of the service within the ECS cluster. Because I have tried both names and both fell over with a container does not exist,, Thinking about it the service will not exist, so it should be the  ECS cluster name. The document does say as it appears in a container defintion. I am not sure what that means. Agian thankyou from stopping me going down a rabbit hole with the aws_lb_target_group_attachment.

Comment: The container name is not the name of the service, and it is not the name of the cluster. An ECS cluster has one or more services. A service has one or more tasks. A task has one or more containers. In the task definition you should be providing a `name` attribute for the container. That is the container name.

Comment: Thank you I worked it out, I created it on the console to see how it works. Again thank you very much. You have been a great help,

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your question.